# How to edit auto scaling from ECS with new UI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to edit the auto scaling in an ECS service.

I used to be able to do that in old UI.

[image]But there is no option to do that in new UI and the toggle to switch back to old UI seems to dissapear.

Answer (score 1):

- View the list of clusters in ECS
- Click the name of the cluster to go into cluster details
- Click the name of a service to go into service details
- Click the "Update Service" button
- Scroll down to the "Service Autoscaling" section of the service details (it's near the bottom of the page)